# Build input file cannot be found: How to change path of file [xcode]

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using react native for showing webview of my page in android and ios.

I have changed package name in android and my app.json file to new name. Everything is working ok with android.

Now when I try to build project in ios using xcode I have error

> Build input file cannot be found:
> '/Users/admin/restapp/restapp/ios/RestApp/main.m' (in target
> 'RestApphhopp' from project 'RestApp')

> Build input file cannot be
> found: '/Users/admin/restapp/restapp/ios/RestApp/AppDelegate.m'

Which really doesn't exist on that path.

This files are located in **/Users/admin/restapp/restapp/ios/RestApphhopp/**

Anyone knows where to change this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding the where you can see the path and change them in Xcode. Click the little right arrow near of .swift
[image]

Comment: place where all folders you have, for example app delegate or group folder etc,  it seems on the right when click on them